# Performing matrix operation on two large matrices

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, matrix

I have two large matrices (40000*4096) and I would like to compare and match each row of the first matrix to all of the rows for the second matrix and as a result, the output will have a size (40000*40000). However, since I need to do this for several thousand times, it is wildy time consuming 26k seconds for each iteration so for 5000 times ...
I would be glad if you could give me some smart suggestion. Thank you.
P.S. this is what I did so far for just one iteration (1 of 5000)

```py
def matcher(Antigens, Antibodies,ind):
    temp = np.zeros((Antibodies.shape[0],Antibodies.shape[1]))
    output = np.zeros((Antibodies.shape[0],1))
    for i in range(len(Antibodies)):
        temp[i] = np.int32(np.equal(Antigens[ind],Antibodies[i]))
        output[i] = np.sum(temp[i])
    return output
output = [matcher(gens,Antibodies) for gens in Antigens]
```

Comment: You may want to try doing this in a language more geared for numerical computation, like Julia/Fortran/C++. If not, this is a great candidate for parallelization.

Comment: Thank you, do you mean multiprocessing or multithreading or something else?

Comment: Otherwise, there are subtle optimizations you could do. Initialize `temp` and `output` as empty arrays, not as zeros. Remove the type-casting `np.int32` and just set `dtype=np.int32` on `temp` initialization.

Comment: I mean [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html). PETSc would be a decent candidate for this but the current Python bindings look weak.

Comment: What sort of "match" do you need?  If this is an unrestricted check of some sort, then you're stuck with an N*M algorithm.

Comment: @Prune I want to compare the elements and get a binary output of 1/0.

Comment: @DanielR.Livingston Thanks a lot

Comment: Are there any duplicates, or is there only one possible match?  What is the usage of this match table?  Do you need to have reference to the matching object -- it appears that you're looking for an *exact* match, so the vector in `Antigens` is equivalent.

Comment: You should look into using the python numpy package. it has great matrix functionality, and compiles down to optimized fortran code. (https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/index.html)

Comment: @Matt ...he's clearly already using numpy in his example code.

Comment: Please let me know if I have it right: you have to make 5000 antigen and antibody matrix comparisons (each are 40000 x 4096). You're comparing each row/array in an antigen matrix against all the rows/arrays in the antibody matrix. This comparison returns 1 if ALL elements of the rows match (or are you summing number of matches?). The result per pair is a 40000 x 40000 matrix of 1's and 0's, representing matching rows between antigens and antibodies (or a number between 0-4096 in the summing case). In the end, you'll have 5000 of these matching matrices?

Comment: @ernestk The comparison returns a sum of the number of matches. So for one iteration the resultant matrix will 40000x1. And I will be doing this 5000 times.

Comment: What kind of hardware are you working with (in terms of nodes, cores, ram, and gpus)?

Comment: Which dtype are the arrays? How many matches do you expect (more like 20% or more like 0.x%? The opposite way, finding definitely not matching rows first, can be far simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I understand what your goal is:

Count number of row matches (antigen vs antibody matrix). Each row of the resulting vector (40,000 x 1) represents a count of exact matches between 1 antigen row and all of the antibodies row (so values from 0 - 40_000).

I made some fake data:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

num_mat = 5       # number of matrices
num_row = 10_000  # number of rows per matrix
num_elm = 4_096   # number of elements per row
dim = (num_mat,num_row,num_elm)

Antigens = np.random.randint(0,256,dim,dtype=np.uint8)
Antibodies = np.random.randint(0,256,dim,dtype=np.uint8)
```

There's one important point here, I reduced the matrices to the smallest datatype that can represent the data in order to reduce their memory foot-print. I'm not sure what your data looks like, but hopefully you can do this as well.

Also, the following code assumes your dimensions look the fake data:

*(number of matrices, rows, elements)*

```
@nb.njit
def match_arr(arr1, arr2):
    for i in range(arr1.shape[0]): #4096 vs 4096
        if arr1[i] != arr2[i]:
            return False
    return True

@nb.njit
def match_mat_sum(ag, ab):
    out = np.zeros((ag.shape[0])) # 40000
    for i in range(ag.shape[0]):
        tmp = 0
        for j in range(ab.shape[0]):
            tmp += match_arr(ag[i], ab[j])
        out[i] = tmp
    return out

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def match_sets(Antigens, Antibodies):
    out = np.empty((Antigens.shape[0] * Antibodies.shape[0], Antigens.shape[1])) # 5000 x 40000
    # multiprocessing per antigen matrix, may want to move this as suits your data
    for i in nb.prange(Antigens.shape[0]):
        for j in range(Antibodies.shape[0]):
            out[j+(5*i)] = match_mat_sum(Antigens[i], Antibodies[j]) # need to figure out the index to avoid race conditions
    return out
```

I lean on Numba heavily. One of the key optimizations is not to check the equivalence of entire rows with `np.equal()` but to write a custom function `match_arr()` that breaks as soon as it finds a mis-matched element. Hopefully, this lets us skip a ton of comparisons.

Time comparison:

```
%timeit match_arr(arr1, arr2)
314 ns ± 0.361 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit np.equal(arr1, arr2)
1.07 µs ± 5.35 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

`match_mat_sum`

This function simply calculates the middle step (the 40,000 x 1 vector) that represents the sum of exact matches between two matrices. This step reduces two matrices like: *(m x n), (o x n) -> (m)*

`match_sets()`

The last function parallelizes this operation with explicit parallel loops through `nb.prange`. You might want to move this function to a different loop depending on what your data looks like (like if you have one antigen matrix, but 5000 antibody matrices, you should move `prange` to the inner loop or you'll not be leveraging parallelization). The fake data assumes some antigen and some antibody matrices.

Another important thing to note here is the indexing on the `out` array. In order to avoid race conditions, each explicit loops needs to write to a unique space. Again, depending on your data, you'll need to index the proper "place" to put the result.

On a Ryzen 1600 (6-core) with 16 gigs of RAM, using this fake data, I generated a result in 10.2 seconds.

Your data is about 3200x times larger. Assuming linear scaling, the full set would take approximately 9 hours, assuming you have enough memory.

You could write some kind of batch loader as well, rather than loading 5000 giant matrices directly into memory.

Comment: with regards to matching each row of the antigen to all rows (i.e. the whole 40000x4096), i want the output after one row (of antigen matching) to give me a 40000x1(where row will be from 0 to 4096). And hence after comparing all the rows of the antigen matrix with the whole of the antibody matrix, i will have 40000 40000x1 matrices or a 40000x40000 matrix. I will be repeating the whole process for about 5000 times....i really appreciate your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be tackled with a mixture of numpy broadcasting, and the module numexpr, which performs operations fast while minimizing the storage of intermediate values

```
import numexpr as ne

# expand arrays dimensions to support broadcasting when doing comparison
Antigens, Antibodies = Antigens[None, :, :], Antibodies[:, None, :]
output = ne.evaluate('sum((Antigens==Antibodies)*1, axis=2)')
# *1 is a hack because numexpr does not currently support sum on bool
```

This may be faster than your current solution, but for such large arrays it will take a while.

The performance of numexpr for this operations is a bit lackluster, but you can at least use broadcasting inside the loop:

```
output = np.zeros((Antibodies.shape[0],)*2, dtype=np.int32)
for row, out_row in zip(Antibodies, output):
    (row[None,:]==Antigens).sum(1, out=out_row)
```